# Why Webpack doesn't copy over my ng2 template files?

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack

here is my (simplified) Angular 2 app folder stucture:

[image: My Angular 2 app folder structure]

And here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './vendor.ts',        
        'app': './app/main.ts'},
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js",
        sourcemapFilename: '[name].map'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']},
            {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html'
            },
            {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            ,{ test: /\.css$/, loaders: 'style!css' }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
            }),       
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

When I execute webpack build, **dist** folder gets index.html, app.js, polyfills.js and vendor.js only.
app.component.html, css and users component html files are not copied over (in respective folders, app, app/users...) to dist folder.

[image]

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

This is how it looks from Dev Tools:

[image: Template gets 404]

Comment: It look like your templateUrl is not being complied. could you please share your components's code

Comment: `@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],`   This is how it was defined. It worked with System.js, failed in webpack.

Comment: Do you have code on github? in your webpack ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader'] shouldn't be ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']

Comment: Did you got a fix for this?

Comment: @Govan Like in the answer below, I've recreated my app with Webpack example from Angular Docs. Double checked template URLs as well because after an update to typescript (or Webpack it was, I don't remember) relative paths were no longer problem. Since then I have no problems in my projects. But at that time I couldn't solve it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works. the plugin angular2-template-loader look for the templateUrl and convert path in component

from

```
templateUrl; 'path'
```

to

```
 `require("templatePath")`
```

what webpack understand and build it in bundle.js with the component. you can see your build and find for something like this

```
 template: __webpack_require__(id).
```

It doesn't create separate html files for you it bundle all in one and serve you as request. as your webpack there are going to be only app.js, pollyfills.js , vendor.js and index.html

Here is example of full component how it looks

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: "./home.template.html",
})
```

and in your webpack

```
{test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ["ts-loader","angular2-template-loader"]},
```

Comment: Check the added screenshot to my initial question above. angular2-template-loader may be working the way you state it does, yet problem I had is probably hidden somewhere else in my webpack.config.js because I'm getting 404 on full URL, not to an ID.

Comment: Look into you bundle if it's been compiled or not it should be `require("templatePath")`

Answer (score -1):

I've couldn't manage to convert my app and make it work this way, so I've created a clean project following steps described in Angular Docs [Webpack: an introduction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html), then copied over my components one by one, checking errors I get when built, mostly wrong path locations, and then correct them. It seems to work so far.

Comment: @JorawarSingh A day passed after I've asked this question and during that time I've solved my problem, whether you like my method or not, and I've shared it. Also I've made an observation about possible cause of error, shared that information as well, all those are written above.

Comment: yes i understand that a day passed but still there will be other looking at your post for find the same answer so it's better to give an detailed and explained answer. as you asked in your question that "app.component.html, css and users component html files are not copied over". I only mean to contribute so other can understand what's going on thanks!